# Отсчет даты

Tags: дата, php

У меня дата 28.12.2014, и мне надо, чтобы показало от 28 до сегодняшнего дня

и выведет так:

28.12 | 29.12 | 30.12 | 31.12 | 01.01 | 02.01 | 03.01 | 04.01 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю как-то так:

```
<?php

$start_date = '28.12.2014';
$date = strtotime($start_date); // преобразовали строку с датой в unix format

// пока дата меньше текущей
while ($date<=date()){
    echo date('d.m', $date); // выводим ее в формате д.м
    $date = strtotime('+1 day', $date); // переключаем дату на следующий день
}
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку

date() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in

Comment: Нет под руками php-копилятора. Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: @Get

    date() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in

Comment: Замените while($date<=date()) на while($date<=time())

Функция date() используется только для форматирования даты, а time() как раз возвращает метку текущего времени.

Comment: Работает. Спасибо.